# What is wrong with this query (unexpected token: AND)

Tags: apex, soql

Can anyone whats wrong with this Query

```
 SELECT Id,name,Email,MobilePhone,MailingCity FROM Contact WHERE  Key_Skills__c = 'C++' OR  MailingCity = 'Austin' AND ( Id Not IN : applicantId ) LIMIT 1000
```

it gives an error

> unexpected token: AND

I am generating this query dynamically in apex

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mix the `OR` and `AND` operators with out parenthesis. The working query will be:

```
SELECT Id, name, Email, MobilePhone, MailingCity 
FROM Contact 
WHERE (Key_Skills__c = 'C++' OR MailingCity = 'Austin') 
       AND ( Id Not IN : applicantId ) 
LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Logically speaking even we cant say what is 1 OR 2 AND 3 is ?

So you need to make it clear:

```
SELECT Id,name,Email,MobilePhone,MailingCity FROM Contact WHERE  (Key_Skills__c = 'C++' OR  MailingCity = 'Austin') AND ( Id Not IN : applicantId ) LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Operator precedence is usually the way that such ambiguity is resolved. In Apex, the `&&` operator takes precedence over the `||` operator, so it would be evaluated as `1 || (2 && 3)`. It appears that SOQL operators don't have a similar precedence structure though. Definitely seems like one of those things that should be mentioned in the documentation (though it doesn't appear to be).